# Why Recaptcha is not working with an url with params?

Tags: php, recaptcha

I did a Recaptcha integration and, it is working wonders with the domain of my site:

http://landing.acrdev.com/

But it does not work with an URL with params http://landing.acrdev.com/?idioma=es&cod=Santander2021&utm_source=web-sitio web&utm_medium=banner&utm_campaign=precio_especial?

And it returns me a message in spanish: Hubo una incidencia! ... Y no pudimos guardar sus datos. Favor de intentarlo más tarde!

I am looking for the error documentation or something but, I did not find any.

Comment: hi, perhaps the parameters are causing the server-side logic to fail before displaying the full content?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Without the recpatcha, it works fine, but I will check... :(

Comment: You are right, I debug and is a server-side logic fail... Duuuuh!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I find the problem, it was a server side problem... sns!